# Mail.app notification filtering

Tags: mail.app, notifications, growl

Is it possible to disable notification generated by Mail.app for a certain set of folders?

For e.g. if have `Inbox` and `Inbox > fol1` & `Inbox > fol2`, I want notification from `Inbox` and `fol1` only.

Would this be possible with growl somehow?

Comment: @ohmantics You can choose to have GrowlMail only show notifications for Inbox (Mail > Preferences > GrowlMail > Only notify for emails in your Inbox).

Comment: yup, that is what I am using now

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by setting up Rules in Mail.app that filter on the criteria you desire and then run an AppleScript that triggers a Growl notification. Rules are setup in Mail.app under Preferences…->Rules.

Growl can be called from AppleScript as shown [here](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php).

Comment: basically, there are some annoying folders with tonnes of emails coming in which i really should convert to digests, but I digress. I don't want notifications for these folders, only for a select few. And while growl can be invoked that way, I will have to somehow disable all notification and then add this logic and rules for each folder, am I right?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: Mail rules only run on mail that is in the Inbox. If you are moving the messages on the client side (in Mail.app) you could add the Growl notification (via AppleScript) there, if your mail is filtered on the server then this will not work.

Comment: Yup, I am doing server side filtering. What i was wondering was if there was a way to filter messages in growl based on text, cause the subjects have folder names. That could be a way of doing this. Maybe I should ask a separate question

Comment: Growl doesn't have the kind of filtering you're looking for. Adding one rule per folder name in Mail.app isn't that complicated. Once you make one rule that works the way you want, you can just duplicate it and edit the new folder name in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Smart Mailboxes to filter the mailboxes viewable,

http://www.cultofmac.com/185867/only-get-notifications-for-a-specific-mailbox-in-mountain-lion-os-x-tips/